# open page on marker click using leaflet and ionic 2

Tags: angular, leaflet, ionic2

I created map in ionic 2 using leaflet library. And also added marker

[image]

```
let marker = L.marker([47.561495, 7.592376]).addTo(this.map);
```

My question is how can I open page on marker click.

I am doing something like this.

```
marker.on('click', this.onMarkerClicked);
...

onMarkerClicked() {
   this.navCtrl.push(SomePage);
}
```

But it gives following error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try `marker.on('click', ()=> {this.onMarkerClicked()});`